# Kernel Panic on 2016 15'' 10.12.6 Mac after Sleep: "Failed to complete supporting devices sleep"

Tags: sleep-wake, kernel-panic

During the last couple of days, my MacOS running 10.12.6 started to display the "Your computer restarted because of a problem" screen after waking up from sleep, which according to my research is a Kernel Panic.

It seems to do this every time I put it to sleep. I tried to fix it by resetting the NVRAM and SMC on my computer to no avail (assuming I've done that right,) but I have the following report:

```
    Wed May 17 13:49:53 2023

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7fa0825cd9): "Failed to complete supporting devices sleep/wake\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleEmbeddedOSSupport/AppleEmbeddedOSSupport-59.60.8/Source/Drivers/AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost/AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost.cpp:460
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff820b0d3e50 : 0xffffff801d8e837c 
0xffffff820b0d3ed0 : 0xffffff7fa0825cd9 
0xffffff820b0d3f00 : 0xffffff801d92144a 
0xffffff820b0d3fb0 : 0xffffff801d898957 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost(1.0)[52F33EB3-E16C-3340-980B-03ED8DC4C79D]@0xffffff7fa0824000->0xffffff7fa0829fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7f9e08a000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
16G2136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Sun Jun  2 20:26:31 PDT 2019; root:xnu-3789.73.50~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9778BC83-2647-3AE4-A7F2-8A2F41FA8791
Kernel slide:     0x000000001d600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801d800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801d700000
System model name: MacBookPro13,3 (Mac-A5C67F76ED83108C)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 304453944528
last loaded kext at 10668840171: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs  1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f9e800000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 129996873468: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7f9fc65000, size 40960)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.42
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.42
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.42
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.42
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
com.Apowersoft.driver.AudioDevice   1.6.7
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.17
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.14.52b52
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.5.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   279.48
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.5f7
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4100   1.5.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMD9510Controller    1.5.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphics  10.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.14.52b52
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSKLGraphicsFramebuffer   10.2.5
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 114
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1152.2.1a2
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   174
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  5.0.5f7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.5f7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 279.48
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.5f7
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   159.12
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.14.52b52
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   516.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 279.48
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.15
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.5.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.14.52b52
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    311.16.4
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    515.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394.50.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540.30.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   199
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  368.16
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    76.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    49
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  49
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.0.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.50.19
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro13,3, BootROM 259.71.1.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.38f7
Graphics: Radeon Pro 455, AMD Radeon Pro 455, PCIe, 2048 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 530, Intel HD Graphics 530, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x15A), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.134.1a2)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.5f7, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Network Service: Thunderbolt Bridge, Ethernet, bridge0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: iBridge
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

What should I do? Thanks.

[image: Here is a picture of it]

Comment: I'd start by only sleeping it with no external devices connected, followed by uninstalling Soundflower & Apowersoft. Report back.

Comment: I did what you said @Tetsujin and then restarted and it seems to work! Thanks!